# twisted ReverseProxy connectionMade

Tags: python, proxy, twisted, reverse-proxy

I am trying to build a reverse proxy (with twisted). The reverse proxy listens on ports 6000-6099 and should map those ports to different internal IP addresses. Once a connection is made to a port, it should do some pre-checks, like starting a virtual machine in a cluster.

Example:

```
PublicIP:6000 -> do pre-check -> forward traffic to InternalIP-1:6800
PublicIP:6001 -> do pre-check -> forward traffic to InternalIP-2:6800
...
```

I modified an example I found [here (section 'Proxies and reverse proxies')](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html). But I can't get it to work. Can anybody help?

```
from twisted.web import proxy, http
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
import sys
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

machines = {}

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    protocol = proxy.ReverseProxy

    def connectionMade(self):
        if not machines.has_key(self.request.port): # self.request.port?!
            # start new machine in cluster 
            # machines[self.request.port] = new_machine_ip

        # reverse proxy to machines[self.request.port] on port 6800
        # return proxy.ReverseProxyResource(machines[self.request.port], 6800, '/')

for port in range(6000,6100): 
    reactor.listenTCP(port, ProxyFactory())
reactor.run()
```

**Edit:**

- How can I get the port of the current request?
- How to pass traffic to the internal IP?

Comment: What does 'can not get it to work' mean?

Comment: I edited my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted actually has a built in `ReverseProxyResource` for this purpose, where the request object is passed to the `render` method.  It can be extended and modified to do the dynamic routing as you like.

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.proxy.ReverseProxyResource.html

The [simplest example is here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/reverse-proxy.py), though you are free to override the resource methods to do the kind of checking you describe.

`Site` in this example is a factory that is using the regular HTTP protocol.